# How to add properties to controls that are created in a class ASP.NET C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, app-code

I have this in my App_Code folder. I am creating a custom control for uploading files. I need to add AllowMultiple property to the FileUpload control .How do I do it? See the comments in the code to see where the fileupload, cannot figure out how to do it from msdn website.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Security.Permissions;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for MultiFileUpload
/// </summary>
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
namespace MyControls
{
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:MultiFileUpload runat=server></{0}:MultiFileUpload>")]
    public class MultiFileUpload : CompositeControl
    {
        public string tempFolderPath;
        private FileUpload browser;
        private ListBox fileList;
        private Button addToListButton;
        private Button delFromListButton;
        private Button uploadFiles;
        private string uploadPath;
        public string thumbsPath;
      //  [BrowsableAttribute(true)]
       // public virtual bool AllowMultiple { get; set AllowMultiple=true; }
        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
// need to set AllowMultiple=true on here  for the fileupload. If there is a way aspx page that would work too        


            browser = new FileUpload();
            fileList = new ListBox();
            addToListButton = new Button();
            delFromListButton = new Button();
            uploadFiles = new Button();




            browser.Width = new Unit(350);
            fileList.Width = new Unit(265);
            addToListButton.Width = new Unit(75);
            delFromListButton.Width = new Unit(75);
            uploadFiles.Width = new Unit(353);





            addToListButton.Text = "Add";
            delFromListButton.Text = "Delete";
            uploadFiles.Text = "Upload to Site";

            addToListButton.Click += new EventHandler(AddToListButtonClick);
            delFromListButton.Click += new EventHandler(DelFromListButtonClick);
            uploadFiles.Click += new EventHandler(UploadFilesClick);

            this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<table><tr><td colspan='2'>"));
            this.Controls.Add(browser);
            this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td></tr><tr><td rowspan='2' width='20'>"));
            this.Controls.Add(fileList);
            this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td><td>"));
            this.Controls.Add(addToListButton);
            this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td></tr><tr><td colspan='2'>"));
            this.Controls.Add(delFromListButton);
            this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td></tr><table>"));
            this.Controls.Add(uploadFiles);

            base.CreateChildControls();
        }
        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) {base.Render(writer);}
        public MultiFileUpload() {}
        public void SetUploadPath(string path) {this.uploadPath = path;}
        public string GetUploadPath() {return this.uploadPath;}

        private void AddToListButtonClick(object source, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (browser.HasFile) {
                DirectoryInfo tempFolder = new DirectoryInfo(tempFolderPath);
                if (tempFolder.Exists)
                {
                    browser.SaveAs(tempFolderPath + browser.FileName);
                }
            }
            RefreshListBox();
        }
        private void DelFromListButtonClick(object source, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (fileList.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                DirectoryInfo tempFolder = new DirectoryInfo(tempFolderPath);
                tempFolder.GetFiles().ElementAt(fileList.SelectedIndex).Delete();
                RefreshListBox();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using .NET Framework 4.5+, then that property already exists:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.allowmultiple(v=vs.110).aspx

Note that I believe this is HTML5 dependent.

If not, you can use the [Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.attributes(v=vs.110).aspx) property to add additional HTML attributes that will be rendered on the page.

```
browser.Attributes["multiple"] = "multiple"
```

This will *only* work if you website is using HTML5.

You could also derive a new class from FileUpload, add the property to that class, and then override the AddAttributesToRender (or one of the other render methods) method to output the appropriate HTML.

Comment: I am still a beginner and I didn't write the above code. Would you be able to walk me through it . Please?

Comment: You don't need to add it.  It already exists.  Just set browser.AllowMultiple = true.

Comment: I don't have enough information to be more detailed than that.  If you want more detail, then at least tell me what version of .NET you are using.

Comment: Never mind  I am using Asp.net 2.0.5 and that property is not supported. Is there a work around it?

Comment: I've amended my answer.  Since it appears you are not using .NET 4.5, I recommend using the Attributes property to make the file control take multiple files.  However, you may well run into additional complications by doing this.  How will you access the files that were uploaded?  I strongly recommend upgrading to a more recent version of .NET unless you are working with a large, existing project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78268/discussion-between-superuser1-and-nimrand).